# How do i properly link this twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a little project in Symfony. Right now trying to link my twig template (tours.html.twig). 
I have a page loading localy in browser (typing: bikelando.localhost). At this page i have a link to the other page tours.html.twig.
What I am trying to do is to make address bikelando.localhost/tours show the tours template. I think I tried everything on the internet and nothing works. 
This is code in **.../bikelando/templates/index.html.twig** with link to tours

```
<a ... href="{{ path('tours') }}">Tours</a>
```

this is my **.../bikelando/config/routes.yaml** code (which is working for index.html.twig but not for tours)

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    defaults:
        template: 'index.html.twig'
tours:
    path: /tours
    controller: App\Controller\ToursController::show
```

and this is my **.../bikelando/src/Controller/ToursController.php**

```
class ToursController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/tours", name="tours")
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return $this->render('tours.html.twig');
    }
}
```

All of this gets me 404 error when i type **bikelando.localhost/tours**, app not loading this template, but **bikelando.localhost** is loading OK. I am very confused and exhousted, can someone point my mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hi, you are using annotations and yaml routing together, choose one. (I suggest yaml 10/10 times)

Comment: This is my annotations.yaml file
```controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
return $this->render'@BundleName/folder_in_views/tours.html.twig');
```

Also, be sure that the Apache module url_rewrite is activated.